# Error 405 when trying to log in. Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm using Python 2.7 and Flask with Bootstrap:

When I log in my website, the page 405 Method Not Allowed shows after submitting my username and password. They do exist in the database and the page should at least show an error message.

The login function in my **init**.py:

```
@app.route('/login/', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def login():
try:
    c, conn = connection()
    error = None

    if request.method == 'POST':

        data = c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = (%s)",
                        thwart(request.form['username']))
        data = c.fetchone()[2]

        if sha256_crypt.verify(request.form['password'], data):
            session['logged_in'] = True
            session['username'] = request.form['username']

            flash("Welcome "+str(session['username'])+"! You are now logged in.")
            return redirect(url_for("dashboard"))

        else:
            error = "Invalid credentials, try again."

    gc.collect()

    return render_template('login.html', error = error)

except Exception as e:
    flash(e)
    error = "Invalid credentials, try again."
    return render_template('login.html', error = error)
```

And here is my login.html file:

```
{% extends "header.html" %}

{% block body %}
<body>

<div class="container">

    <br>

    <h4>Please Login:</h4>
    <br>
    <form action="" class="form-inline" method="post">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder = "Username" name="username" value="{{request.form.username}}">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder = "Password" name="password" value="{{request.form.password}}">
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>

    {% if error %}
        <p class="error"><strong>Error:</strong> {{ error }}</p>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="container">
        <br>
        <p>No account? <a href='/register'>Register here</a>.</p>
        <br>
        {% for paragraph in Body_info %}
        <p>{{ paragraph }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

</div>

</body>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Try specifying form action to your login url `/login` or `url_for`

Comment: it is very weird because the problem solve itself...
I've spent 2 days looking for a solution and it solved itself without any reason.

Comment: I've spent 2 days looking for a solution and it solved itself without any reason. The server (@ Digital Ocean) updates properly, other changes too. It migth come from a bug in either Flask/Python, notepad++ or WinSCP, even apache2.
I don't know so if someone has experienced similar trouble(a bug for no reasons).
Try copy/pasting or rewriting the code (even with the exact same logic) somewhere else in the file. I'm 100% sure I didn't change anything at all into my original code, simply removing temporarely some variables to find the problem.